# my shopifiy store footer wont align in the center of my website

Tags: css, sass

[I need this to be vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLxk.png)

[it wont center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3LZ7.png)

i need everything in the photos to be vertically aligned and centered ive tried

> #footer-logo {   margin: 0 auto; }
>
> #site-footer __rte rte p, em {   align-text: center; }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting - also read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Model 1 */
.flx-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* Model 2 */
.flx-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-wrap">
    <div class="flx-center">block1</div>
    <div class="flx-center">block2</div>
    <div class="flx-center">block3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).